# Magento V1.8 one page checkout not loading payment information

Tags: checkout

Please, can someone assist me? I am having an issue with my one-page checkout on `Magento CE v1.8.`

I am testing the checkout process and noticed that after selecting a shipping method the system fails to move onto the next step which is `"Payment Information"`. When I click on the `continue` button nothing happens and it remains on the shipping method tab.

I am new to Magento and still playing around with it so I wouldn't be surprised if it's a stupid setting or an overlooked issue because of my lack of experience with the system.

But I read somewhere that it may be a JS error or something from the template.

The link is http://beachandbeyond.co.za/shop and any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: In admin panel go to `System->Configuration`. Then Click the `Payment Methods` tab and check whether payment methods are enabled or not?

Comment: Hi Su123 I do have payment options enabled. It works with the default template just not my current theme.

Comment: Better to compare the checkout.xml of your custom theme with the default theme checkout.xml. And check if any missing parts. (Check specifically the contents between the handler `<checkout_onepage_index>`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a problem with the markup in the payment section.
When the shipping method step is completed this js should be executed:

```
$('checkout-'+response.update_section.name+'-load').update(response.update_section.html);
```

`response.update_section.name` is `payment-method`

but `$('checkout-payment-method-load')` returns null because there is no element with that id in your DOM.
Make sure that this file in your theme `checkout/onepage/payment/info.phtml` has the following content:

```
<dl class="sp-methods" id="checkout-payment-method-load">
   <!-- Content dynamically loaded. Content from the methods.phtml is loaded during the ajax call -->
</dl>
```

Comment: Hi Marius I have had a look in that file and that code does exist. shop/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/info.phtml

It works with the default theme, so I am guessing it must be an issue with the current them. I have tried contacting the seller for info, but to no avail.

Now I have a deadline rolling in and getting desperate.

So any further assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to look at the default theme layout file for the checkout and make it look similar to the one in your theme. Give special attention to this block `<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/info.phtml"> `

Comment: I located these two files.

The default template file was found here, shop/app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/checkout.xml and the theme file here shop/app/design/frontend/default/beautyshop/layout/checkout.xml

The block code you refer to is the same, except that the custom theme calls a methods.phtml file instead of info.phtml file.

I tried to change the methods.phtml to info.phtml in the file code but I still experienced the issue.

Comment: the default ones are in `app/design/frontend/base/default`

Comment: I have played around with the suggested files, to no avail. I have changed the methods.phtml to info.phtml to no effect. I even copied all the code from the default checkout.xml to the custom theme checkout.xml to no effect. Cleared the cache and tried again. I'm no coder, so maybe I am messing up but I think I have followed your instructions pretty well.

Comment: Think I may have found it. Will revert soon.

Comment: Ok so it seems the issue was that info/methods code. And the fact that I didn't do a cache flush may have contributed to not seeing the changes initially. Stupid mistake. But now the "Your Checkout Progress" column on the right doesn't show any information in it as you go through the steps.... :(

Comment: That may be related to the fact that your theme is not for 1.8 and the order progress mechanism has changed in 1.8. See this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes

Comment: Its suppose to be compatible with Version 1.8.

Comment: I've found many extensions that are listed compatible (with version after they were created), are BUT there are bugs as you have found.

Answer (score 18):

As it has been said in the comments the error is located in the `checkout.xml`.

Here is the faulty code in the `custom template`:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
```

And should be replaced by:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/info.phtml">
```

This error was found on a `templatemonster` template.

Comment: This did the trick.